# Servlet to Javascript

Tags: javascript, servlets

In my `servlet.java`,

```
request.setAttribute("f4stat", "Somedata");
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("my.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Now, in `my.jsp`, in a `javascript` function I would like to access this `f4stat` data.

How to do it in Javascript?

I've tried,

```
var x = '<%= request.getAttribute("f4stat")%>'
if (x.length == 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "<b> data </b>";
    }
```

But this is not working as in my `<div id="display">` no content is being displayed even when `f4stat` has no value.

Comment: u may update this line in jsp: var x = '<%= request.getAttribute("f4stat")%>' to this one: var x = '${requestScope.f4stat}';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access HttpRequest ,HttpResponse objects of servlet in JavaScript. 
But This is possible by trick.

You Can Have Some Hidden Fields in my.jsp and assign value.

```
<script>
    function getF4(){
          document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=document.getElementById("f4").value;
    }

</script>

     <input type="hidden" id="f4" value=<%= request.getAttribute("f4stat") %>  />
     <input type="button" value="click" onclick="getF4()" />
     <div id="display"></div>
```